# Radiobuttonlist não aceita no if o SelectedIndx

Tags: c#

Tenho esse RadioList declarado:

```
<label>Aprovar</label>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAprovar" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;Sim&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;Não&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" Value="0" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

E tenho esse comando em meu behind:

```
if(rblAprovar.SelectedIndex = -1)
  {
    vstrMensagem += "- Aprovar não informado.<br>";
  }
```

Isso está dando esse erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'bool'

Tenho outros Radiobuttonlist com o mesmo if que não dá esse erro e que eles estão sendo programados da mesma forma. A pergunta é: O que pode estar errado nessa declaração? Na minha opinião nada.

Comment: Faltou o ==... `if(rblAprovar.SelectedIndex == -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O que pode estar errado nessa declaração? Na minha opinião nada. @pnet

No seu if você está atribuindo um valor para SelectedIndex =, você deve utilizar == para verificações booleanas.

```
if(rblAprovar.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {
    vstrMensagem += "- Aprovar não informado.<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Tens razão, a pressão é grande e nem percebi isso. Que merda e um post denecessário. Um pouco de atenção e cuidado como todo programador deve ter e isso seria evitado. Pecamos às vezes em coisas mínimas. Desculpe-me a todos. O fato de eu estar em uma pressão muito grande, esse post deveria ser desnecessário.

Comment: Calma colega, só se vive uma vez @pnet